# JMeter save unencoded Request (Sampler) parameters

Tags: testing, jmeter

I've made my test plan and set up samplers, assertions, listeners and so on.
My Http Samplers post XML data to an URL sending a parametrized encoded http request.

In my listeners I'm able to save many info about any sample, but I'm not able to save in the sample information the XML request sent in the request parameter **without encoding**.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**

Here is an example of the exported listener:

```
<httpSample t="1001" ts="1376663141980" lb="Caso 1 (VI16)" rm="OK" by="648">
    <assertionResult>
        <name>Response Assertion</name>
        <failure>false</failure>
        <error>false</error>
    </assertionResult>
    <responseData class="java.lang.String">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;ISO-8859-1&quot;?&gt; [... the rest of the html encoded response ...]</responseData>
    <cookies class="java.lang.String"></cookies>
    <method class="java.lang.String">POST</method>
    <queryString class="java.lang.String">data=%3CFastBankRichiesta+%3E+%0A%09%3CTestata+NomeMessaggio%3D%22VI16%22+Timestamp%3D%2220130816162541928%22 [... the rest of the URL encoded request ...]</queryString>
</httpSample>
```

So, the request and the response are encoded, but while the response is correctly html encoded (because I choosed XML export), the request is URL encoded; how to apply decoding back to text and html encoding in order to see request and response correctly with a web browser?

Comment: could you clarify with an example ?

Comment: I've added an export example from the listener.